# find alphanumeric elements in vector

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have a vector

```
    myVec <- c('1.2','asd','gkd','232','4343','1.3zyz','fva','3213','1232','dasd')
```

In this vector, I want to do two things:

1. Remove any numbers from an element that contains both numbers and letters and then
2. If a group of letters is followed by another group of letters, merge them into one.

So the above vector will look like this:

```
'1.2','asdgkd','232','4343','zyzfva','3213','1232','dasd'
```

I thought I will first find the alphanumeric elements and remove the numbers from them using gsub.
I tried this

```
    gsub('[0-9]+', '', myVec[grepl("[A-Za-z]+$", myVec, perl = T)])

    "asd"  "gkd"  ".zyz" "fva"  "dasd"
```

i.e. it retains the `.` which I don't want.

Comment: Not sure what you mean doesn't work. I'm getting false for each of the strings that contain numbers, i.e. at indices 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, and 9. Is that not what you're expecting with this first step?

Comment: I'm assuming your issue is that `1.3zyz` is not recognized, and thus excluded for number removal? You are asserting start that letters start the string, so just remove the `^` from your call: `grepl("[A-Za-z]+$", myVec, perl = T)`

Comment: @camille I am expecting the code to only return true for the alphanumeric and not for numeric or letters

Comment: I have edited my question for clear explanation

Comment: use `gsub('[0-9\\.]+', ' ', myVec[grepl("[A-Za-z]+$", myVec, perl = T)])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to return what you are after

```
myVec <- c('1.2','asd','gkd','232','4343','1.3zyz','fva','3213','1232','dasd')


clean <- function (x) {
  is_char <- grepl("[[:alpha:]]", x)
  has_number <- grepl("\\d", x)
  mixed <- is_char & has_number
  x[mixed] <- gsub("[\\d\\.]+","", x[mixed], perl=T)
  grp <- cumsum(!is_char | (is_char  & !c(FALSE, head(is_char, -1))))
  unname(tapply(x, grp, paste, collapse=""))
}

clean(myVec)
# [1] "1.2"    "asdgkd" "232"    "4343"   "zyzfva" "3213"   "1232"   "dasd"
```

Here we look for numbers and letters mixed together and remove the numbers. Then we defined groups for collapsing, looking for characters that come after other characters to put them in the same group. Then we finally collapse all the values in the same group.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my regex-only solution:

```
myVec <- c('1.2','asd','gkd','232','4343','1.3zyz','fva','3213','1232','dasd')

# find all elemnts containing letters
lettrs = grepl("[A-Za-z]", myVec)

# remove all non-letter characters
myVec[lettrs] = gsub("[^A-Za-z]" ,"", myVec[lettrs])

# paste all elements together, remove delimiter where delimiter is surrounded by letters and split string to new vector
unlist(strsplit(gsub("(?<=[A-Za-z])\\|(?=[A-Za-z])", "", paste(myVec, collapse="|"), perl=TRUE), split="\\|"))
```